# GDI+ WinForms Program works differently on different computer

Tags: winforms, gdi+

I wrote a vb 2015 GDI+ WinForms program on my desktop. It works perfectly there. It involves a 600x600 image, and clicking on the image changes the color of a 10x10 box on that image where the mouse clicked. But, on my laptop, clicking on the image changes that 10x10 box and also three other boxes outside the image, to the right, to the right lower, and to the lower ( i.e. East, Southeast, and South) areas of the form outside the image.

```
 For example, clicking on the Desktop gives:  -------
                                              | x    |
                                              |      |
                                              -------
 While clicking on the Laptop gives:          -------
                                              | x    |  x
                                              |      |
                                              -------
                                                x       x
 .
```

Both machines are Windows 7 Pro 64-bit SP1. It doesn't matter which screen resolution is used - they all work correctly on the desktop, and they all work incorrectly on the laptop.

It also doesn't matter whether the program is installed on the machine's hard drive or is running from a thumb drive (the same thumb drive on both machines).

Also, loading a bitmap into the desktop's image works properly, while loading the same bitmap into the laptop's image produces four copies: one properly within the image's boundaries and the other three to the East, Southeast, and South, as with the mouse click results.

I haven't provided my code here because it's quite lengthy. At the moment, I'm just looking for some ideas regarding what might cause such a problem.

Comment: I know WinForms fairly well, and I can't come up with anything off the top of my head that could be causing this just by reading your question. Maybe I don't entirely understand it. But I think it's unavoidable that we're going to have to see sample code that reproduces this problem. It's best if you actually don't post your entire application, but rather [a minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Did you try some debugging? I'd look into the mouse click event handlers and where the drawing actually happens to see whether these "extra" clicks originate from your own code or the OS.

Answer (score 0):

Do you use a different characters sizes in window  ? (eg the zoom functionnnality)

I found a lot of problem with many application when the size is not set to 100% (Default) (from ugly gui to freeze).